# How to capture JSON key and values as an array in powershell

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, scripting, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a json output from an api call, which partially looks like as below.
As part of this json, there are many id and name values listed..Now, I want to capture  id and name pair together as an array , as part of some steps in the program I get returned with name , I want to compare this name with the name stored in array previously and return the id value corresponding to it.
As I have to pass this id value to another rest api call.

Could someone help how can I capture this array through powershell?

```
$Json = '{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "datafactory.git",
            "size": 0,
            "remoteUrl": "",
            "sshUrl": "",
            "webUrl": "",
            "isDisabled": false
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "datafactory",
            "defaultBranch": "refs/heads/main",
            "size": 13569,
            "remoteUrl": "",
            "sshUrl": "",
            "webUrl": "",
            "isDisabled": false
        },
    ]
}'
```

Comment: I'd start with `ConvertFrom-Json` to get your Json into powershell objects and go from there.

Comment: Yes, I had done that, but how can I capture both id and name as a pair together, so that I can  compare the name with some value obtained from script and output the id value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a [**hash table**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) for this:

```
($Json |ConvertFrom-Json).Value |ForEach-Object {
    $HashTable = @{}
} {
    $HashTable[$_.name] = $_.id
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$HashTable.datafactory
2
```

---

You might also consider to refer to the complete value property object (instead of just the `id`):

```
($Json |ConvertFrom-Json).Value |ForEach-Object {
    $HashTable = @{}
} {
    $HashTable[$_.name] = $_
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$HashTable.datafactory.id
2

$HashTable.datafactory.size
13569
```

Comment: Thanks iRon, I was trying to do a comparison and printing, but I have an issue there..could u pls suggest..          $reponame = "repo" if($reponame -eq $HashTable.$reponame){
    echo $HashTable.$reponame.id
}
else{
    echo "not compared"
}

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I guess you actually want to see whether the `reponame` exists: `if ($HashTable.Contains($reponame)) { $HashTable[$reponame].id } else { "$reponame doesn't exist" }`